# Identify newly created files and process them

Tags: java

Basically I have to monitor the folder for newly created files.

In my project ,we have a scheduler which runs after every 10 min ,now what we do is read all the file names and check in database if it is already processed or not if not processed then make a entry in DB and process it.

I googled it and found few solutions involving listner to the path like JNotify , FileAlterationObserver class along with FileAlterationMonitor but there are around 20 folders i have to monitor so i was looking for any simpler solution like whenever i read a file mark it as processed (rename it and append "*Processed*" to its name or any unique text) and next time read files which are not marked "*processed*".

With this approach , I will have to read all the files from folder and check for every file name whether it ends with "*Processed*" or not.

I am new to jave so i dont know whether it is possible or not ,So my question is ,Can i query all the file names which are not ending with "*Processed*" without iterating over all the file names present in the folder ?

Or anybody has any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Once processed do we need the file anymore? Who is modifying the files? If it is via a program the, will that program needs the information about already processed files? When that program going to modify the file are going to rename it again from **file1_processed** to **file1**?

You have to think about these use cases and many more if you change the file names (though I don't know in and out about your system but I felt it would be complected).

Better you just us `JNotifier`, it is really simple to use. Using this you can actually remove the scheduler. Whenever a notify comes for a particular files (added/modified etc), you can actually update the database that time only for particular that file only, no need traverse through the folders.

Just make sure in few cases you can get multiple notification in `JNotifier`, e.g. when new file added, you get added, modified, when renamed you get renamed, modified. So these things you have to take care.

With old scheduler also you can do the same. you can save the last updated timestamp of a file in the database. in next schedule you just check the latest timestamp, if timestamp is newer then process it and re-update the database.

Also you can do the mix of `JNotify` and scheduler. By jnotify you update the changed/modified file names in some `ADT`, scheduler can search inside the ADT, gets the modified files path and update those files only in database.

You can take help from the below example,

```
public void register(String path) throws JNotifyException {
        int mask = JNotify.FILE_CREATED | JNotify.FILE_DELETED
                | JNotify.FILE_MODIFIED | JNotify.FILE_RENAMED;
        boolean watchSubtree = true;
        if (pathSet.contains(path)) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Adding watch for: " + path);
        JNotify.addWatch(path, mask, watchSubtree,
                new JNotifyListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void fileCreated(int arg0, String folderName, String fileName) {
                        fileChanged("New object created: " + fileName + " in folder: " + folderName);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void fileDeleted(int arg0, String folderName, String fileName) {
                        fileChanged(fileName + " deleted in folder: " + folderName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void fileModified(int arg0, String folderName, String fileName) {
//                      fileChanged(fileName + " modified in folder: " + folderName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void fileRenamed(int arg0, String folderName, String oldFileName,
                            String newFileName) {
                        fileChanged(oldFileName + " renamed to: "+ oldFileName +" in folder: " + folderName);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void fileChanged(String str){
        //your code here
    }
```

Comment: Once processed we do not need that file any more and we just need newly created files so i dont need modified,deleted action but i have to monitor 20 such paths so should i use JNotifier because if it fails for some reason then that will be big concern

Comment: if you don't need the processed file then you can simply move them out of your folder and put them into some archive folder. when your program search inside the original folder, it doesn't get those processed files, only gets the new files. With this you don't have to check any condition like processed or not etc... So your program performance and maintainability will increase.

Comment: yup,But moving them to another folder means a new folder on server ,I am not sure we can do that because archiving is any way automated control m job which archives 1 month old files.

Comment: Yes but that automated program also you can change. The automated program then can check directly to the folder where you have moved the file from base folder, and if it is one moth old then can be moved to archive folder by the automated tool. I don't have knowledge about your full product. It might be possible some solution given by me won't be feasible for your product. You can filter my suggestions and can come up with a suitable solution.

Comment: yes ,changing a control-m job is not a option for me.Thanks Abhinaba for you comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change file names, then it is fine for you to rename the file to 'old_file_name + Processed' and then, process only those that their names don't end with processed.

Comment: Can i query all the file names which are not ending with "Processed" without iterating over all the file names present in the folder ?